# What is the most painless way to check whether a $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity, proof-writing

Given

$f(x_1,x_2) = \begin{bmatrix} x_1^2 + x_2 \\ x_1 + x_2^2\end{bmatrix}$

and

$g(x_1,x_2) = \begin{bmatrix} 2x_1 & 1 \\ 1 &  2 x_2\end{bmatrix}$

In my class I am only taught the $\epsilon-\delta$ method, but oh boy is that method tedious and painful, even for trivial looking functions such as $f(x) = x^{3/2}$ you need divine intervention to fully carry out the proof. There must be a better way, especially given that $f$ and $g$ are obviously continuous elementwise.

What is the "best" way to show that $f,g$ are continuous?

Comment: In fact, a vector-valued or matrix-valued function will be continuous if and only if every "component function" is continuous.

Comment: A function to $\Bbb R^n$ is continuous iff each of its components is a continuous function. Polynomials are continuous.

Comment: You say you were taught only the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method. Were you not taught such theorems as: a sum of continuous functions is continuous? a product of continuous functions is continuous? a composition of continuous functions is continuous? an $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued function is continuous if and only if its component functions are continuous?

Comment: @LeeMosher No, not a mathematician, just going through first course on rigorous math for engineers. Imagine if you were only taught area approximation method and not the integral, you would probably go around asking how to find the area under $x^2 + e^x$ given that its area is kind of hard to approximate

Comment: Fair enough. But what I would suggest, then, is that you learn those kinds of basic applications of the $\epsilon,\delta$ method. And then, you learn how to apply them to problems like yours. I'll write up an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some basic theorems which themselves are proved using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method. The way one would approach this problem is to use those theorems (which, of course, have to be proved, but those proofs can be found in any reasonable "advanced calculus" textbook).

First there is a theorem saying that for any function $f=(f_1,f_2)$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f$ is continuous if and only if $f_1,f_2$ are continuous. More generally, for any function $f$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (take $n=4$ for your matrix example), $f$ is continuous if and only if each of its $n$ component functions is continuous. Hence, you need only prove that the various component functions are continuous, namely: 
$$h(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2+x_2 \,\,\text{or}\,\, x_1 + x_2^2 \,\,\text{or}\,\, 2x_1 \,\,\text{or}\,\, 1 \,\,\text{or}\,\,2x_2
$$

Next, there is a theorem saying that constant functions are continuous. This is extremely easy to prove using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method. That polishes off the constant function $h(x_1,x_2)=1$, or any other constant function such as $h(x_1,x_2)=2$.

Next, there is a theorem saying that a sum of continuous functions is continuous. Hence, you only need to prove that the various summands are continuous, namely: 
$$h(x_1,x_2) = x_1 \,\,\text{or}\,\, x_1^2 \,\,\text{or}\,\, x_2 \,\,\text{or}\,\, x_2^2 \,\,\text{or}\,\, 2x_1 \,\,\text{or}\,\, 2x_2
$$
Next, there is a theorem saying that a product of continuous function is continuous. Hence, you only need to prove that the various factors are continuous, and having already done so for constant factors, we are down to
$$h(x_1,x_2) = x_1 \,\,\text{or}\,\, x_2
$$
Finally, those last two functions are known as the coordinate projection functions, and there is a theorem saying that the coordinate projection functions are continuous.

Generally speaking, the knowledge of continuity is built up hierarchically, as this example shows. For example, the same basic method that I've outlined above produces the theorem that any polynomial function is continuous, as said in the comment of @PeterFranek.